# matplotlib 3D surface plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter

Trying to create a 3D surface plot of a plane with jupyter notebook.  However, this code is giving me a strange error:

```
# ValueError: Argument Z must be 2-dimensional.

%matplotlib
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
plt.clf()
ax = Axes3D(fig)

x=np.arange(-4,4,1)
y=np.arange(-4,4,1)

X = []
Y = []
Z = []

for ix in range(0, len(x)):
    for iy in range(0, len(y)):
        z = 2*x[ix] + 3*y[iy]
        Z.append(z)
        X.append(x[ix])
        Y.append(y[iy])

ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z)

plt.show()
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Where are you getting the error? Please post the Stacktrace and the specific details of the problem you are encountering, so we can help you better.

Comment: It's not strange at all, rather, you can take this literally: `Z` must be a 2D array. Recheck the [plot_surface example](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/mplot3d/surface3d.html). In your case `X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y); Z = 2*X+3*Y`.

Answer (score 1):

```
%matplotlib inline
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

X = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.25)
Y = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.25)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)

def plot():
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = Axes3D(fig)
    #ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
    ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z)
    plt.show()

Z = 2*X + 3*Y
plot()
```